# AppArmor/Certbot error: cannot change profile for the next exec call: No such file or directory

Tags: server, apparmor, letsencrypt

Ubuntu 20.04.3.  This is a server that I upgraded last winter from 16.04 to 20.04.  I use Webmin/Virtualmin to do day-to-day management. As a renewal for a LetsEncrypt cert came to be due last week, I started getting an error: "cannot change profile for the next exec call: No such file or directory". The Webmin people have not seen it before and I get the error message when I try certbot from the commandline, so I don't think it's involved.  The people at letsencypt gave a valiant effort in trying to find the problem, but have come up empty:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/letsencrypt-error-cannot-change-profile-for-the-next-exec-call-no-such-file-or-directory/164500

But it seems that this is an AppArmor issue.  I have checked the /var/log/kern.log logs and one frequently listed is:
audit: type=1400 audit(1635877257.770:584): apparmor="DENIED" operation="change_onexec" info="label not found" error=-2 profile="unconfined" name="snap.certbot.certbot" pid=3272017 comm="snap-confine"

What does this mean?  Anything else I should be looking at?  There are no log files in /var/log/apparmor.

Thanks!